# Server.UrlEncode Encode DataNavigateUrlFormatString

Tags: c#, asp.net, urlencode

How can I url encode the `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` property? Sometimes the `FN`   value contains a # which messes up my `Request.QueryString["FN"]`   .

Below is what I have tried

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="reportFileName" 
                        DataNavigateUrlFormatString='<%#Server.URLEncode("PDFViewer.aspx?FN={0}")%>' Text="View" 
                        HeaderText="View" Target="_blank" />
```

But I receive error: Error  3   Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField does not have a DataBinding event.